# How to draw a red 'X' in a specific coordinate by clicking in a qlabel with a pixmap using pyqt5?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qpixmap, qlabel

I would like to allow the user to click on a Qlabel (containing a pixmap) at a specific coordinate in order to draw a red point or perhaps a red cross and to extract the specific pixel coordinate in pixmap coordinate system. As I understood, Qpixmap has no mousePressevent and the maximum that I could implement was to print the coordinates of the click in respect of label coordinates.
One problem is that when I resize my main window the label also resizes and for a fixed position in the label its coordinate changes dramatically.

Another problem is the impossibility of printing the coordinates in respect of the pixmap coordinates. Anyone knows how to print pixmap coordinates on click and not label coordinates?

Thanks

Comment: QPixmap is not Widget so you do not have the mousePressEvent method as you mentioned, you could indicate that it is what you want to get, you want the pixel position or you want to get the color of the pixel, in the case of the position it is impossible, but we place a QLabel with the size of the QPixmap because when you resize the QLabel the QPixmap pixels are altered. The specific question is what you want to get and what you want to use, with the second answer you could give other options.

Comment: I want to get pixmap coordinate when label clicked. But when resizing my window, label also changes its dimensions; for a specific point with coordinates (a,b) these vLues are no longer a and b when i resize my window

Comment: Do I need to be a QLabel? could give you a better solution if it is a custom widget